# last_sql_error of command show slave status in replication MySQL

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

i have a question concerning the alias LAST_SQL_ERROR and LAST_SQL_ERRNO that we get in command  SHOW SLAVE STATUS. Is there command that can recover to me just these two aliases.
the command show slave status recover all the information about replication, i want just to recover last_sql_error end last_sql_errno.
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to do this until MySQL 5.7, when that information is available in the [`performance_schema.replication_execute_status_by_coordinator`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-execute-status-by-coordinator-table.html) table.

If you are on an older version (which you almost certainly are) then you'll probably need to execute `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` and parse the output in the language of your choice to extract the fields you are interested in.

Comment: first thank You for the answer, please what do you mean by other languge, do you mean if i want to make an interface in a language like Java

Comment: You could script this pretty easily in bash, python, perl, etc.

Comment: My purpose is to make an interface that can generate the error of statment on slaves when it is executed on the master, my interface will have two button the first is skip using set global sql_slave_skip_counter=1 and the second correct to correct the error. the interface has also an area for showing the last_sql_error  that why Im thinking about command. do you have idea how can get it in the interface.i beg your pardon